# Jquery Codeigniter - Autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I am facing a problem with autocomplete in codeigniter. When inserting some text on input, it shows a dropdown but no value in there. Looks like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyBZK.png)

Viewing error on console : [Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HCMN.png)

Here is my code :

**Model**

```
var $unit_table = "sales_unit";
public function getUnit($searchTerm)
{
    $this->db->like('nopol', $searchTerm, 'both');
    $this->db->order_by('nopol', 'ASC');
    $this->db->limit(10);

    return $this->db->get($this->unit_table)->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function jsonUnitAutocomplete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $result = $this->m_admin->getUnit($_GET['term']);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row)
                $data[] = array(
                    'nopol'  => $row->nopol,
                    'type' => $row->type,
                    'kategori' => $row->kategori,
                    'seat' => $row->seat
                );
                echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="npl" id="drop-npl"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tyunit"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kg"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="seat"><br>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#drop-npl").autocomplete({
    source: "<?php echo site_url('control_admin/jsonUnitAutocomplete') ?>",

    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('[name="npl"]').val(ui.item.nopol);
      $('[name="tyunit"]').val(ui.item.type);
      $('[name="kg"]').val(ui.item.kategori);
      $('[name="seat"]').val(ui.item.seat);
    }
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't you just read incorrect query param name? and in the Controller you not declare else statement for your if-else, so the result will be undefined

From what I noticed, I assumed **No.Polisi** is input text with the name **"npl"**. So you can change **'term'** on your controller into **'npl'**, like below:

```
function jsonUnitAutocomplete()
{
    if (isset($_GET['npl'])) {
        $result = $this->m_admin->getUnit($_GET['npl']);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row)
                $data[] = array(
                    'nopol'  => $row->nopol,
                    'type' => $row->type,
                    'kategori' => $row->kategori,
                    'seat' => $row->seat
                );
                echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but i have a problem in autocomplete when im replaced them on $_GET which is still not showing